# Why can't you return a reference to a temporary?

Tags: rust

Why can't you return a reference to a temporary in Rust? The motivating example is:

```rust
fn what<'cellref, 'cell: 'cellref>(x: &f64) -> &'cellref CellValue<'cell> {
    &CellValue::Number(*x)
}
```

One might think that the compiler could infer that the object needs to live as long as the reference exists, and so keep it alive until the reference is dropped. Why can't the compiler infer this?

As requested, here is an MRE. It illustrates a simple problem: suppose an API is expecting a `&T`. Where do you store the `T` so that it lasts as long as the desired `&T`?

```rust
pub enum CellValue<'a> {
    String(&'a String),
    Number(f64),
    Boolean(bool),
    // ... many more types ...
}

pub enum Array<'a> {
    ArrayGeneric(ndarray::Array2<CellValue<'a>>),
    ArrayF64(ndarray::Array2<f64>),
    ArrayString(ndarray::Array2<f64>),
    // .. many more types ...
}

impl Array<'a> {
    pub fn generic_iter() -> Iterator<Item = &CellValue> {
        // ?
    }
}
```

Like in many rust use cases, the goal is abstractions that are zero-cost.

As motivation, suppose that you have an excel spreadsheet and you are defining an "array" of cells that can be passed around between excel functions. Sometimes, this will be a literally range of values in the spreadsheet. At other times, you may have applied a transformation, like `ABS(...)`, and now you have an array of the absolute values of a range of cells. In the former case, you need only store the full spreadsheet and a few `usize` to locate the range. In the latter case, you need to store all the values. Values can be Strings, numbers, or other values, so you'd like a generic Array that handles mixed values, or perhaps single-type Array that handle only f64, only String, etc.

Comment: `and so keep it alive until the reference is dropped` This is basically reference counting, which Rust intentionally doesn't use as its primary lifetime handling.

Answer (score 6):

Whether the compiler can infer this is irrelevant, because there is no *mechanism* by which the compiler can realize this request.

Remember that Rust doesn't have a (built-in) garbage collector, so the compiler can't just emit instructions to allocate the enum value on the heap and let the GC take care of it. It needs somewhere to store the value that will live at least as long as `'cellref`, but also will not outlive `'cell`.  It cannot fabricate such a location; you would have to give it one (in the form of a `&'x mut CellValue<'cell>` where `'x: 'cellref`, for example).  Alternatively, you could just return `CellValue<'cell>` instead of returning a reference.

The type of code in your question can work for purely constant values, because the compiler *does* have a location to place such values: it can emit the value into the text section of the binary and return a reference to that.  In fact, this is exactly what happens with string literals!  The problem here is that `x` is not a compile-time constant, but a reference whose referent is not known until runtime.  Therefore, the compiler cannot build a `'static` instance of `CellValue`.

Contrast with this code, which does indeed compile:

```
fn what(x: &f64) -> &'static CellValue<'static> {
    &CellValue::Number(&42.0)
}
```

There is a workaround: you can [leak a `Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak). The obvious downside here is that the memory holding the `CellValue` is permanently leaked and cannot be reclaimed until the program terminates.

```
fn what<'cell>(x: &'cell f64) -> &'cell CellValue<'cell> {
    Box::leak(Box::new(CellValue::Number(x)))
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't answer a fundamental question: the compiler *knows* when the *reference* is no longer being accessed: after all, the reference is stored in variables and function parameters just like a value. So how do you allocated the value to be stored somewhere and cleaned up when the reference is no longer accessible?

Comment: The Box example is interesting, but the motivating example is simple: if the compiler is passing a reference around, how do you get the referenced object to be cleaned up when the reference is?

Comment: @Test No, the compiler does not know that. The function `what` is evaluated in isolation. The compiler doesn't know what other code is going to call `what` nor what it's going to do with those references. The definition for `what` including its lifetimes _must stand alone_ (types notwithstanding). Again, the compiler would need somewhere to put the value that is guaranteed to outlive the referent, and it cannot do this without intrusively modifying the return type in some way.

Comment: @Test _"how do you get the referenced object to be cleaned up when the reference is?"_ You don't, not in Rust. It really sounds like this function should return a value, not a reference. This strongly smells of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) so it might be helpful to provide more context. It's possible you might be after some kind of shared ownership (`Rc` or `Arc`).

Comment: Sure, if you believe it's an XY problem, the bigger problem is: an API expects an iterator of &CellValue, and I'm trying to map an iter of f64 to &CellValue and then pass it to the API. This is much the same as a box, but there are just multiple items.

The core thing I don't understand is: &T is a type just like T. Rust can keep track of whether T is accessible. So why can't it do the same for &T?

Comment: @Test `&T` means "reference to a `T` that lives somewhere else." Can you tell me where the compiler should put the `T` that is _guaranteed_ to outlive the reference in all cases, short of leaking a box? Because I can't think of _any_ such place. In the case of your iterator issue, it may be helpful to open a new question with a complete [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of that issue, because there is probably a much better solution than what you're attempting.

Comment: @Test To clarify, lifetime annotations are how you prove to the compiler that your references won't outlive their referents. This is how the compiler "keeps track of whether `&T` is accessible." The fact that you can't figure out a way to express this function in a way that satisfies the compiler is a very strong hint that you simply can't do it this way.

Comment: That's not my question. Rust can figure out when `T` goes out of scope. Why can't it figure out `&T`? The values of type `&T` are stored in variables, passed between functions, and referenced just like `T`—all the patterns Rust uses to infer when `T` is accessible.

Comment: @Test It _does_ figure that out -- that's why the code doesn't compile: because the compiler knows that the `&T` lives longer than the `T`. In this case, the `T` (`CellValue`) is a value local to the function, and it ceases to exist when the function returns. Your function attempts to return a reference to a value that is about to stop existing, and the compiler knows this won't work, which is why you get a compile-time error. To be clear, this type of function __will compile in C++__, however it will exhibit __undefined behavior__ at runtime, which Rust is protecting you from here.

Comment: That makes 100% sense, except, if Rust understood when the value needed to exist until, you would think that Rust could simple make it exist until then, or you could tell rust to make it exist until then.

Comment: For your benefit, I've made an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77740871/rust-mre-generic-iterators) to see if it is an "XY Problem".

Comment: @Test Again, Rust is looking at the function `what` in isolation. It does not care what else is going to call it; the definition of this function must make sense all on its own. To understand how long the referent needs to live, it needs to know what happens to the reference _after it's returned from this function_ (which would require analyzing the entire call graph) and then it would need to _change data structures in the program_ to accommodate this -- something Rust simply doesn't do.

Comment: That makes sense—you're saying it can't be known statically, it would need to change data in the program to know when it disappears. However, this is the only reference to the object. If I returned a simple object, Rust would know when it went out of scope simply by tracing variable scope and function closures. Why can't it do the same with a single reference to an object?

Comment: @Test It can, but a "simple object" _doesn't refer to another value._ A reference does, so Rust requires that the referent must exist at least as long as the reference. The answer to your question "why can't Rust track this" is that _Rust does track this and that's why the code fails to compile._ Because it tracks both the reference and the referent and says "hey, the referent ceases to exist _before the reference ceases to exist and __this is a use-after-free bug.___"

Comment: @Test *"So how do you allocated the value to be stored somewhere and cleaned up when the reference is no longer accessible?"* - references do not do that. If you want that behavior then you need a `Box`/`Rc`/`Arc` instead.

Comment: Using a `Box/Rc/Arc` means allocating the reference to the heap. This is an entirely useless step when the reference is needed only inside the Iter.

Comment: @Test They mean instead of a `&T` you would have `Arc<T>` (not `Arc<&T>`), but to avoid copies this requires that you already have an owned `T` that you can move into the `Arc`.

Comment: Doesn't `Arc<T>` require heap allocation? Where can I read about the performance differences of these?

Comment: Yes, it does, but it also allows you to share ownership of a `T` such that it will live as long as the `Arc` wrappers and also be destroyed when the last `Arc` handle is. The heap is not always a bad thing. (However, based on the discussion happening on the other question, you still likely want `Cow`.)

Comment: @Test `Arc` does require a heap allocation -- but in all GC'd languages, the reference type you're talking about ("So how do you allocated the value to be stored somewhere and cleaned up when the reference is no longer accessible?") *is implemented with a heap allocation!* But Rust isn't a GC'd language, and its *reference* type is *fundamentally different* from the one you're looking for. In GC'd languages, *references* determine the lifetime of the data. In Rust, the references don't keep the value alive, they are *constrained* by the lifetime determined by the owned data.

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions here, and I will attempt to answer them both:

1. What specific rule(s) of Rust does the function in question break?
2. Why do those rules exist?

#### 1. The rules being broken

By the rules of the language, the referenced temporary is destroyed when the function returns.

> Temporaries that are created in the final expression of a function body are dropped after any named variables bound in the function body. **Their drop scope is the entire function**, as there is no smaller enclosing temporary scope. -- *[Rust Reference, §10.8 "Drop Scopes"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html?highlight=drop%20scope#temporary-scopes)*

Consider the simple (invalid) function:

```rust
fn example() -> &String {
    &String::from("hello")
}
```

The final expression of the function body is `&String::from("Hello")`. The value is owned by the temporary created by the function call `String::from("Hello")`.

> The block of a function is conceptually wrapped in a block that binds the argument patterns and then **returns the value of the function's block**. *[Rust Reference, §6.4 "Functions"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/functions.html?highlight=return#function-body)*

These two rules conflict. **The value is not owned by the returned reference** (because references do not own values), and thus is destroyed when the function returns. Thus the reference cannot be valid, as the value it would have pointed to no longer exists.

You can't get around this restriction with lifetimes, because **all lifetime parameters to a function outlive the function**. You can do this:

```rust
fn get_an_element<'a>(slice: &'a mut [String]) -> &'a String {
    // Move the value into the scope called 'a.
    slice[0] = String::from("hello");

    // Return a reference to it.
    &slice[0]
}
```

but not this:

```rust
fn make_a_reference<'a>() -> &'a String {
    // Return a reference to the temporary owned by the function.
    &String::from("hello")
}
```

because `'a` refers to some scope that outlives the function. The first example stores its value in the scope called `'a`; the second stores its value in the anonymous scope of the function body, which terminates when the function returns.

---

#### 2. Why the rules exist

(This section is non-normative: the compiler doesn't *have* to work as described here, but it does, and likely always will.)

The Rust runtime (it does have one, as does C!) uses a call stack to store the local variables of functions. When a function is called, it receives a stack frame containing its arguments and space to store its locals; when the function returns, its stack frame is destroyed. This is the model used by most programming languages<sup>[citation needed]</sup> that aren't Lisp (which can use [continuation passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)).

As a result, if you try to return the value of a temporary, you're asking for the compiler to generate code that returns an address within a now-destroyed stack frame, which will be clobbered the next time you call a function.

The compiler *could* refcount the variable (like Python), or do escape analysis (like Go), or employ some other technique to keep the value alive until no longer needed. But the language is designed to be as explicit as reasonably possible, and to run in a large number of environments. The value has to live somewhere; if the stack frame it was born in ceases to exist, you must store it elsewhere, or it disappears as well.

Comment: `example` is an unfortunate example since it [fails to compile due to no lifetime elision available, not a dropped temporary](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7f3dff447fe43f9693cc8199e64c2b73). For the same reason `make_a_reference` is completely valid!

Comment: Huh, TIL from my own bad example that temporaries that impl `Copy` will get extended past the bounds of a function. Changing the value to be non-`Copy` (e.g. `String`) produces the expected error.

Comment: Rust being explicit is helpful, but if you want a particular function to behave with refcount or escape analysis, how do you do it?

Comment: Refcounting is provided by `Rc<T>` and `Arc<T>` for single- and multi-threaded programs, respectively. Rust does not perform escape analysis because the storage location of values is always explicit; values are stored on the stack unless deliberately moved to the heap through `Box<T>`, `Vec<T>`, etc. By contrast, in e.g. Java, non-primitive values are _semantically_ always heap-allocated, and escape analysis is used to opportunistically avoid actual heap allocation.