# Rust MRE: Generic iterators

Tags: rust

This is an MRE requested from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77740828/why-cant-you-return-a-reference-to-a-temporary]. It illustrates a simple problem: suppose an API is expecting a &T. Where do you store the T so that it lasts as long as the desired &T?

```rust
pub enum CellValue<'a> {
    String(&'a String),
    Number(f64),
    Boolean(bool),
    // ... many more types ...
}

pub enum Array<'a> {
    ArrayGeneric(ndarray::Array2<CellValue<'a>>),
    ArrayF64(ndarray::Array2<f64>),
    ArrayString(ndarray::Array2<f64>),
    // .. many more types ...
}

impl Array<'a> {
    pub fn generic_iter() -> Iterator<Item = &CellValue> {
        // ?
    }
}
```

Like in many rust use cases, the goal is abstractions that are zero-cost.

As motivation, suppose that you have an excel spreadsheet and you are defining an "array" of cells that can be passed around between excel functions. Sometimes, this will be a literally range of values in the spreadsheet. At other times, you may have applied a transformation, like `ABS(...)`, and now you have an array of the absolute values of a range of cells. In the former case, you need only store the full spreadsheet and a few `usize` to locate the range. In the latter case, you need to store all the values. Values can be Strings, numbers, or other values, so you'd like a generic Array that handles mixed values, or perhaps single-type Array that handle only f64, only String, etc.

Comment: This MRE doesn't compile. In particular, `&CellValue` needs a lifetime parameter -- should that be `'a` or something else?

Comment: That's the question: what should the lifetime be? You might imagine that someone will call `array.generic_iter().fold(|...| { ... })`, immediately summing the references and so they are no longer needed. At a minimum, `'a: `b` if `&'b CellValue`

Comment: Do you have control over this API? Because _by far_ the simplest approach would be to return an iterator of `CellValue` instead of `&CellValue`, especially since `CellValue` is a relatively small value in the first place, so there's not really a huge need to avoid copying it around.

Comment: CellValue can contain values that are slow to clone. Returning the base type would require cloning, which would be expensive.

Comment: What values can it contain that are slow to clone? Can you hold a reference to those instead, like you do with the `String` variant? (By the way, that variant should probably hold `&str` instead of `&String`.)

Comment: It can contain `Lambda` functions, which are arbitrarily complex expressions and also contain a scope variable, which can be mutated. It may also contain mutable references to arbitrarily large `Sheet` objects. The real version has `String(String)`, not `String(&'a String)`. If it were changed to the latter, this would introduce exactly the same problem: where do you store the `String` when you only need a single reference to it.

Comment: In that case I'd assume you'd get the referent from e.g. the `ArrayString` variant. In that case the iterator would produce `CellValue<'a>` values and dispense references to the values contained in the `Array<'a>`, wrapped in the appropriate `CellValue` variant. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't understand how that would work. You're running into exactly the same problem. The fundamental issue is: you want a generic type that is sometimes just a virtual reference to a string of cells (e.g. cell A1 through B5), and is at other times concrete values (strings or large, mutable data structures). When it's concrete values, where do you store them so the end user can treat both as a simple iterator?

Comment: You could use a `Cow` - which is a wrapper that contains either a reference or owned value. It's in the standard library.

Comment: Is that not the job of the `Array` struct? It sounds like the MRE doesn't actually illustrate the real challenge you're facing. The values either exist in advance or they don't; if they don't, returning a reference is not useful anyway since you have to construct them on the fly. If they do already exist, then you can return a reference to them in some form.

Comment: You want to write generic code that works in both cases. Sometimes it's a reference, sometimes it's not. That means you want to return everything as a reference. The problem with `Cow` is that sometimes you want to modify the original data structure.

Comment: "if they don't, returning a reference is not useful anyway since you have to construct them on the fly" - this is the fundamental misunderstanding. You want code that works for both cases. So even if a concrete value works in theory some of the time, you want it to be consistent with code that expects references.

Comment: _"you want to modify the original data structure"_ -- Within `generic_iter` or you want to allow the code doing the iteration to modify the referent?

Comment: No, just you don't want to store everything as a Cow in the structs.

Comment: You don't have to store it as a `Cow`. You can decide _during iteration_ whether the value can be borrowed, or whether it needs to be owned (because e.g. it needs to be tweaked). So for example, the `CellValue::String` variant would be `String(Cow<'a, str>)`. Now it can hold a borrowed string with `'a` lifetime, or an owned string.

Comment: Using a `Cow` allocates to the the heap. This shouldn't need to happen: If it's a simple Iter, you should be able to simple pass the literal reference to the object, not a reference to a reference (Cow) to the object. My only question is where to store objects when they are not already created.

Comment: @Test No, `Cow` does not allocate to the heap. It sounds exactly like what you want. In the `Borrowed` variant it only holds a reference; in the `Owned` variant it holds an owned value inline (not on the heap, though the owned value itself might allocate to the heap, e.g. `String`, but either way, the `Borrowed` variant never causes an allocation).

Comment: Interesting, then this, yes, in fact does exactly what I want. I thought that Box allocated to the heap. Where do you read about the performance differences of these? I imagine there is a hit to constantly matching against Borrowed, Owned?

Comment: The odd thing is that I do not, in fact, want to ever copy on write. I just want an object that allows me to work with `T` and `&T` in a generic fashion. Is there something more specific? Even more odd for Cow, I may want to mutate, and in that case I most certainly don't want to copy every time I mutate.

Comment: Ok, could you give an example of using Cow here?

Comment: Please don't ask a new question when you're asked to provide more details. Instead you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77740828/edit) the original question and add the details there.